# How do I validate attribute values based on given map?

Tags: python, pandas

So, I have a set of pairs, let's call it *map X*, that looks this:

```
{'a':(a_1, a_2, a_3),
'b':(b_1, b_2, b_3),
'c':(c_1, c_2, c_3)}
```

and a table that looks something like this:

| Attribute 1 | Attribute 2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | a_1 |
| a | a_2 |
| c | c_3 |
| b | a_1 |
| a | a_2 |
| b | b_3 |

We can see that the fourth record associates b and a_1. However, a_1 does not belong to the list of values associated with b in *map X*. Generally speaking, I want to flag when something like this happens.

Using python (pandas, preferably, but plain python is okay), how do I confirm that each attribute 1 value is paired with a member of the collection of values associated with it in *map X*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First flatten dictionary, so possible mapping second column by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and compare by first column if not equal:

```
d = {x: k for k, v in X.items() for x in v}

df['test'] = df['Attribute 2'].map(d).ne(df['Attribute 1'])
print (df)
  Attribute 1 Attribute 2   test
0           a         a_1  False
1           a         a_2  False
2           c         c_3  False
3           b         a_1   True
4           a         a_2  False
5           b         b_3  False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `apply` on rows

```py
df['isin'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Attribute 2'] not in d.get(row['Attribute 1']), axis=1)
```

```
print(df)

  Attribute 1 Attribute 2   isin
0           a         a_1  False
1           a         a_2  False
2           c         c_3  False
3           b         a_1   True
4           a         a_2  False
5           b         b_3  False
```